# Puppeteer not working with google cloud functions in Node 10 runtime

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I am trying to launch an instance of google chrome in headless mode but getting the following error:

```
Failed to launch the browser process!
/workspace/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-737027/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libgbm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am using puppeteer v3.0.0 with nodejs 10 runtime.
How can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

As the post was about Cloud Functions the above will not work when then function is deployed. This problem is a known issue.

There's some discussion of reverting to Puppeteer 2.1.0,
[github puppeteer issues 5674](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5674)

or

there's a work around:
[github puppeteer issues 5704](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5704#issuecomment-632969782)

My experience:

- I tried the work around but it did not work. Maybe it needs tweaking
  but I had not time to debug.
- I reverted to puppeteer 2.1.0, deployed
  be function with --memory 2048MB and it worked successfully.